# WARNING: Failed to generate report: No data to report error in python using pytest module

Tags: python, pytest, coverage.py, pytest-cov

**sample.py**

```
def sum(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2


def sum_only_positive(num1, num2):
    if num1 > 0 and num2 > 0:
        return num1 + num2
    else:
        return None
```

**test_sample.py**

```
from . import sample

import pytest

def test_sum():
    assert sample.sum(5, 5) == 10

def test_sum_positive_ok():
    assert sample.sum_only_positive(2, 2) == 4

def test_sum_positive_fail():
    assert sample.sum_only_positive(-1, 2) is None
```

**Coverage command:**

```
pytest test_sample.py --cov=sample.py
```

**Error:**

```
platform linux -- Python 3.5.2, pytest-5.4.1, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /home/apathapa/unit_test/warriorframework_py3
plugins: cov-2.8.1
collected 3 items      

test_sample.py ...
[100%]Coverage.py warning: Module sample.py was never imported. (module-not-imported)
Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)
WARNING: Failed to generate report: No data to report.

/home/apathapa/ut/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytest_cov/plugin.py:254: 
PytestWarning: Failed to generate report: No data to report.

  self.cov_controller.finish()


----------- coverage: platform linux, python 3.5.2-final-0 -----------
Name    Stmts   Miss  Cover
---------------------------


========= 3 passed in 0.13s =========
```

**Can anyone help me how to resolve this error?**

Answer (score 48):

`--cov` accepts either directories or package names, not single files. This means that `--cov=sample.py` looks for a package (directory) named `sample` and inside it, a module (file) named `py.py` to record coverage, and fails. Either use

```
$ pytest --cov=sample
```

or

```
$ pytest --cov=.
```

Comment: I got this error just by including a forward slash(`/`) after the directory name like this: `pytest --cov=sample/`. So, if anyone is facing this issue, just remove the forward slash.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue, and got solved by running:
`coverage run -m pytest .`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code.

Comment: This worked for me - thank you for your answer. Afterward, I ran `coverage report -m` to print the report to the console

Answer (score 3):

Rename test files as 'test_' in order to run the below command.

*pytest --cov=<package (directory) or  module (file)>*

**Example**:
Suppose we have two files in a directory:

1. **sample.py**: contains Python code
2. **test_sample.py**: contains unit tests for sample.py
   then coverage command should be:

***pytest --cov=sample***